# Doctrine - mapping doesn't work

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have problem with Doctrine mapping. First of all I'll introduce my two entites:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="header_fotos")
*/

class HeaderFoto extends BaseEntity{

    ....    

    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\App\Webpage\Webpage", inversedBy="headerFotos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="webpage_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $webpage;

    ...
}
```

Second entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="webpages")
 */
class Webpage extends BaseEntity{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\App\Webpage\HeaderFoto", mappedBy="webpage")
     */
    protected $headerFotos;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->headerFotos = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

My problem is with mapping. When I load entity Webpage and try to access all entities of type HeaderFoto it cannot find any relation. I was trying to compare with another working project with Doctrine and everything is the same.

I was trying to change association to OneToOne on the both sides, just for sure. But in this case it returned Exception No mapping found for field webpage.

I will appreciate every help and advice. Thanks for help.

## EDIT

To be more specific, it has problem in class **\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php** in method **getOneToManyStatement**. It tries to load associated objects, but the array **associationMappings** in this class is empty. This is the last thing what I have found out.

Comment: Mapping looks ok. Are you getting any error messages or just an empty result?

Comment: When I have ManyToOne and OneToMany association it returns error Undefined index webpage. It is in the place when Doctrine is loading associations.

Comment: Why the @ORM\Column(type="integer") in HeaderFoto entity? It is not necessary as you have the type by referencedColumnName...